# How do I output entries by their category?

Tags: categories

Ok, so basically I want to loop through categories and output the title of each category along with all the associated entries. Like so:

**Category 1:** Entry 1 Title, Entry 3 Title

**Category 2:** Entry 2 Title, Entry 4 Title

(Where entry 1 and 3 are category 1 - and entry 2 and 4 are category 2)

This was the closest I got:

```
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('jobCategories').find() %}

        {% for category in categories %}

            <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>

            {% for entry in craft.entries.section('people').relatedTo(category).find() %}

                <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
                     {{ entry.title }}
                </a>

            {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be quicker to turn it around: first get all the entries you need, then group those by their category:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('people').find() %}

{% for category, catEntries in entries | group('categoryFieldHandle.first().title') %}
    <h1>{{ category }}</h1>
    {% for entry in catEntries %}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok, just tried that and all it's doing is outputting the section name.

Comment: Try putting .find() behind the first rule.

Comment: Hmmmm, nope still does the same thing.

Comment: Wait, it works now for some reason. I used: {% set entries = craft.entries.find({ section: 'people'}) %} in the end. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Strange, I would think that those two things have the same result ..

Comment: Maybe there was a white space issue or something? anyway it's working now so thanks!